# Date Time convert CDate

Tags: datetime, formatting

How can show date time yyyy-MM-dd HH:MM:ss this format when rdlc language is de-DE ??

I m working on rdlc report and my rdlc report language de-De but i want date time field show en-US language and all fields show de-De language
Code in rdlc expr =Format(CDate(Fields!CreateTime.Value).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:MM:ss"))

Comment: Can you show some sample codes? Is this a report with C# backend that feed data with Dataset objects?